# $x=2t-t^2$ $y=3t-t^3$ at $t=1$ point.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, curves, tangent-line

Find equations of normal and tangent lines at given points.

$x=2t-t^2$

$y=3t-t^3$

at $t=1$ point.

$\frac{dx}{dt}=2-2t$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=3-3t^2$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3-3t^2}{2-2t}$

from here I don't know what to do slope at point $t=1$ becomes $0/0$.

Answer is $3x-y-1=0$ $x+3y-7=0$

Comment: When you get a slope result like that for a parametric curve, it indicates that there is something peculiar about that point, even when the value of the slope can be resolved.  (The graph José Carlos Santos has included shows that there is a "kink" at (1,2) . )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that, if $t\ne1$, then$$\frac{y'(t)}{x'(t)}=\frac{3-3t^2}{2-2t}=\frac{3+3t}2.$$So, $\lim_{t\to1}\frac{y'(t)}{x'(t)}=3$, and therefore the tangent line when $t=1$ is the line with slope $3$ passing through $(1,2)$, which is indeed the line $3x−y−1=0$; see the graph in picture below:

[image]

Comment: Great answer, should the OP not follow the logic in the manipulation; it's worth noting here that Jose has used the identity $$1-t^2=(1-t)(1+t)$$